# How do I save BQ result to csv file?

Tags: .net, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "key.json");
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create("gcp-poc");
string sql = $"SELECT * FROM dataset_sample.sample02 WHERE name='Ram'";
BigQueryParameter[] parameters = null;
BigQueryResults result = client.ExecuteQuery(sql, parameters);
```

I have above piece of code which retrieves the BQ table data, but I could not find any method to save the response as csv file.

I have seen method(CreateExtractJob) to save the complete table data as csv file, but i wanted to save the response of filtered query data.

Comment: Not tried this before but a `CreateExtractJob` on a temp table with the query output?

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS( 
uri = 'gs://bucketname1//filename1*.csv',  
format = 'CSV', 
overwrite = true,    
header = true,     
field_delimiter = ',' ) 
AS     
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName1 FROM projectname.dataset_sample.sample02 WHERE Name = 'Ram' LIMIT 1000000000;
```

**LIMIT** Does the trick here. With LIMIT it creates single file with the name filename10000000000000.csv